# Math class random() method logic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, logic

I'm trying to understand the logic behind this method. For example, I have the following code:

```
  function getRandomArbitrary(min, max){
           return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
           }
```

I know that this function, when called, will call a random number that will be between the minimum and maximum value, but I don't understand how the program does this by decreasing the minimum value from the maximum, adding the minimum value again and then, multiplying the values by the random() method.

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a float between 0 and the limit of (calculus wise on) +1. So multiplying on some other number gives the desired range. E.g if `Math.random()` returned `.3` and the multiplier as a "total range" of 15, you'd get `4.5`.

Comment: The `+ min` bit in your code is to shift the range to the minimum of your function. If "min" were zero, then no shifting need occur..

Answer (score 0):

Remember order of operations here: the multiplication of `Math.random()` and `(max - min)` will occur *before* adding to `min`.

As for how the rest of it works, let's break it down with some example values.
Let's say we're calling this method like so:

```
getRandomArbitrary(3, 10);
```

We're using `min=3` and `max=10`, which makes the rest of the formula look like so (extra parentheses added for clarity):

```
return (Math.random() * (10 - 3)) + 3;
// return (Math.random() * 7) + 3;
```

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), `Math.random()` will return "a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)". By multiplying that random number by another number, we're changing the *range* that we're dealing with.

Our initial lower range is `0`, and `0 * 7 = 0`, so that stays as `0`.
Our initial upper range is `<1` (alllllllmost 1, but always less than it), so if then our new upper range is `<1 * 7 = <7`. So the value `Math.random() * 7` will be a random number between `0` and `<7`.

Last, we're adding the `min` value we want to our result, which *again* will change our range. The lower range will now be `0 + 3 = 3` and the upper range will be `<7 + 3 = <10`, so now we're getting a random number bet